# jquery modal-dialog button close doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, button, modal-dialog

```
$(function () {
        $('#modalDlg2').live("click", function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            loadDialog(event, "/User/Create");
        });
        function loadDialog(event, target) {
            var $dialog = $('<div></div>');
            $dialog.empty();
            $dialog
    .load(target)
    .dialog({
    title:"Novo utilizador",
        modal: true,
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 600,
        show:'fade',
        hide:'fade',
        minHeight: 400,
        resizable: false
    });

     $dialog.dialog( "option", "buttons", {
            "Cancelar": function() { 
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    $(this).empty();
                }         });
            $dialog.dialog('open');
        }            
    })
```

I have a problem with my close button "Cancelar" it should close the modal dialog and then empty it, but it seems that $(this).dialog("close") does not work, and .empty() does.
I've looked everywere for the solution of my problem. Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: syntax error: `$('<div"></div>');`

Comment: Sorry... i had previously added id to the div... But it still opens a modal dialog and does not close it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
$dialog.dialog( "option", "buttons", {
    "Cancelar": function() { 
            $dialog.dialog("close");
            $(this).empty();
    }
});
$dialog.dialog('open');
```

or

```
$dialog.dialog( "option", "buttons", {
   "Cancelar": $.proxy(function() { 
        $(this).dialog("close");
        $(this).empty();
    },this)         
});
$dialog.dialog('open');
```

Comment: Thank you Marco ;) it did work. Now could anyone tell me why i could not use $(this).dialog('close') instead of $dialog.dialog('close')? So that i can prevent future similar mistakes? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Flavio, you can not use $(this).dialog('..') because the scope (context) has changed in the "cancelar" callback. With the $.proxy() function you insert the scope of the outer function (dialog) into the inner function (cancelar) so you have access to the dialog. Hopefully it's understandable.

Comment: Let me just ask you something more Marco, if i would want to create a button in the html page that would do the same as "Cancelar" button how could i do it? i suppose i would use the proxy function and instead of using "this" as context i would use $dialog, no?

Answer (score 0):

I would try putting this in a callback function for the load:

```
$(function() {
    $('#modalDlg2').on("click", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        loadDialog(event, "/User/Create");
    });

    function loadDialog(event, target) {
        var $dialog = $('<div></div>');
        $dialog.empty();
        $dialog.load(target, function() {
            $dialog.dialog({
                title: "Novo utilizador",
                modal: true,
                autoOpen: false,
                width: 600,
                show: 'fade',
                hide: 'fade',
                minHeight: 400,
                resizable: false
            });

            $dialog.dialog("option", "buttons", {
                "Cancelar": function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    $(this).empty();
                }
            });
            $dialog.dialog('open');
        });
});
```

Comment: NOTE: use `.on`, not `.live` for most recent jQuery versions

Comment: Thanks for the tip, i apreciate your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
$dialog.dialog("option", "buttons", { "Cancelar": function() { $(this).remove(); } });
```